# Can I append attributes to Ruby OpenStruct on the go?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openstruct

I am new to Ruby and this is a really basic question, when I searched for adding/appending values to OpenStruct, I couldn't find any resource.

I'm trying to wrap the response body with extra params and the code in place uses OpenStruct. Now I need to append some key/value later in the code before sending the final reponse.

```
OpenStruct.new(
  body : api_response.body
  check1? : true
)
```

I want to add `check2? : false`.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of `OpenStruct` is that you can add new fields on the fly.

```
response = OpenStruct.new(
  body: 'foo',
  check1: true
)
response.check2 = false
p response
# => #<OpenStruct body="foo", check1=true, check2=false>
```

This is the *only* advantage that it has over `Struct`. Using `OpenStruct` incurs a considerable performance penalty, so if you *don't* need to add new fields later, it should never be used (unless of course you absolutely don't care about performance); use `Struct` instead.

However, specifically in your case, Ruby's parser does not allow methods of form `check1?=`, as both the question mark and the equality sign are only permitted at the end of the identifier; i.e. `check1=` is a valid method name, `check1?` is a valid method name, but `check1?=` is not.

tl;dr: Drop the question mark.

Comment: But you can use Hash instead ? You can add key and value on the fly, yes?

Comment: @Rajagopalan Yes, you can use `Hash`. The syntax is different, obvi.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it depending on what works best for the use case.
One can either do a quick fix with something like this

```
openstruct_object.check2? = false
```

OR an elegant way of doing it is to wrap the creation of your OpenStruct instance in a method that accepts the `check2?` param. (This is what I did and it works great with named args!)

```
def wrap_reponse(body, check1 = "your_default", check2: "named_args")
  OpenStruct.new(
    body : body,
    check1? : true,
    check2? : false
  )
end
```

There is a [good blog](https://dev.to/burdettelamar/all-about-ruby-openstruct-4nof) for reference, which I got after considerable google search.